# How to setup Code::Blocks for GLFW development?

Tags: opengl, code-blocks

When I want to create a project in Code::Blocks I get a popup with a lots of options. One of  them is GLFW project. When I select that I have to name my project and set its location, that is not a problem for me, but than I get this window asking me to select GLFW's location:
[image]

I (think I) installed GLFW by typing: "*sudo apt-get install libglfw-dev*" into the terminal.

What should I type to that window?

Result of `sudo dpkg -L libglfw-dev

```
/. 
/usr 
/usr/share 
/usr/share/doc 
/usr/share/doc/libglfw-dev 
/usr/share/doc/libglfw-dev/copyright 
/usr/share/doc/libglfw-dev/readme.html 
/usr/lib 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.a 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libglfw.pc 
/usr/include 
/usr/include/GL 
/usr/include/GL/glfw.h 
/usr/share/doc/libglfw-dev/changelog.Debian.gz 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so
```

Comment: Use `whereis  libglfw-dev`

Comment: @George it prints: "libglfw-dev:" should it help more?

Comment: Yep should be more like `libzfs.so.2.0: /lib/libzfs.so.2.0.0`

Comment: try `sudo dpkg -L libglfw-dev`

Comment: Ok before we go any further type `which glfw` and let me see the output

Comment: Typing "which glfw" prints nothing.

Comment: Ok one minute let me set mine up and report back!

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get it to fine that path but will keep trying and if I succeed will ping you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok after much search I couldn't find a direct way using the `glfw` project template on code::blocks but I saw this tutorial that did that using another means so I hope this help and note after installing `glfw` via `apt` it seems not able to find what it needs after adding the path `/usr`.

Steps:

1. Install the following:

   ```
   sudo apt install libglew-dev
   sudo apt install libglm-dev
   sudo apt install libsdl2-dev
   sudo apt install libglfw-dev
   ```
2. Create a console application and build and run it
3. Then add the required libraries from the menu `projects --> build options`, select the project name on the **left** (important), then go the the `Linker Settings` tab and  use the `Add` button to add the needed libraries such as `GL` etc.

   [image]

   [image]

Link to video source:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KblXpajVpuU

Comment: Typing "sudo dpkg -L libglfw-dev" prints "/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libglfw-dev
/usr/share/doc/libglfw-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libglfw-dev/readme.html
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libglfw.pc
/usr/include
/usr/include/GL
/usr/include/GL/glfw.h
/usr/share/doc/libglfw-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglfw.so
"   What should I do then?  I am not familiar with using external libaries. :-(